# Firestore Cloud functions looping for unknown reason

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some basic code to retrieve data from my firestore data base. I am getting the correct data but for some reason that operation appears to be occurring twice.

The logs show all the documents printed out twice.  This could be really troublesome with more complex operations.  I feel life I'm probably doing something goofy.

```
exports.deleteProject = functions.firestore.document('{userID}/projects/easy/{projectID}').onDelete(event => {

 .........

    console.log(db)
    var collectionRef = db.collection(userID).doc(xxx).collection(yyy);
    console.log(collectionRef)

    var getDoc = collectionRef.get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        });

}
```

The "........" is just string stuff to reference to proper point in that database
Below "=>" indicates a doc pointing to its data.  I cleaned it up for brevity.

Logs:

```
12:04:37.820 PM
info    
deleteProject
tail => { 
info => {
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx => { 
tail => { 
info => {
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx => {
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy => {
```

Comment: Could you show your entire function, what you're doing to trigger it, and also the logs you're seeing?

Comment: Perhaps an unrelated issue, but one you should fix:  `get()` runs asynchronously and returns a Promise, which Cloud Functions needs to know when to end the function.  Change to  `return collectionRef.get()...`.  Described in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).